# Retaining only one of the duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

A table has some duplicate records. Here is a sample:

```
create table TestStage
(
     primKey int,
     name varchar(50),
     Flag varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO TestStage VALUES(12,'DDD','I')
INSERT INTO TestStage VALUES(15,'EEE','N')
INSERT INTO TestStage VALUES(12,'AAA','I')
INSERT INTO TestStage VALUES(16,'MMM','N')
```

`primKey` is the column on the basis of which a record is defined as duplicate or not. So in the above example row 1 and row 3 are duplicates. I need to delete row 1 and retain row 3.

I used the CTE suggested in some other posts as follows:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY primKey ORDER BY primKey) AS [rn]
  FROM 
      TestStage
)
DELETE cte 
WHERE [rn] > 1
```

But this obviously will delete the 3rd row and not the first row.

How do I deal with this? A few things to be noted....

1. This is a sample table. The duplicate records in the actual table and determined by a combination of keys which are not necessarily numeric.
2. I can't create an identity column for the table now.
3. The table has an index on the keys which determine if its a duplicate (in this example primKey) if this can be used.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that ddd is row 1 and aaa is row 3?

Comment: `But this obviously will delete the 3rd row and not the first row.` this is not obvious at all. You have some undeterministic order, so any of the row can be deleted

Comment: I was just giving you an example of how the table looks. What I need is for a latter row in the table to be picked.

Comment: In over() order by appropriate columns...what is the problem?

Comment: This is an indexed table. So there is an order correct?

Comment: Can you tell looking on 2 rows which is first which is last? If no there is no order.

Comment: Actually in your posted table there is no duplicate records. You are missing that point here.

Comment: Giorgi so what your saying is even if the table is indexed on primKey, the row that comes up lower in a select statement is not the latter row?

Comment: @that_me123 are you actually reading what I'm writing? I have explained at length that your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @that_me123, yes, you can see anything on your monitor. Now it can be one order, but on some other machine the engine can show in different. Even on your machine may be under high load engine can parallelize your query and you will see that row that came at top can now come in end or middle. Unlees you specify order by clause there is no order

Comment: Calling a non-unique column `primKey` is VERY misleading.  There is no way to delete the "last" record, unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: These records were loaded to the table from a flatfile. And i assumed(I'm wrong I know now) that the last record in the file for a particular primKey would be the last record in the table because it was indexed on that column.

Comment: @that_me123 add a sequence number column to the flat file or something else that you can use to compare rows by order. There really is no way to reliably have order once the data is inside of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your misunderstanding is that you think that the table has some intrinsic order. No table has order. Queries must establish order. You need to define some meaningful `ORDER BY` clause to determine which rows to delete.

If you have relied on "table order" and have no other way to pick rows there is nothing you can do.

Right now your `ORDER BY primKey` thing has no effect at all because in each partition all `primKey` values are identical. This is the same as `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`.

> highest value of row number for that partition to be retained

There is no such thing as an intrinsic row number. You need to come to terms with that fact.

Comment: This is correct saying and per my understanding there is no duplicate in OP's posted sample table. He is missing that point completely.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but I don't think that `order by (select null)` and `order by primkey` are necessarily the same thing.  Do you know if SQL Server short-circuits the sorting for `order by primkey`?  It does (at least in many cases) for `order by (select null))`.

Comment: partition by x order by x is equal to partition by x (agreed?). This rewrite is probably implemented. Even if it wasn't implemented the additional sorting keys would not change anything about the output from an implementation standpoint. The windowing function usually is implemented as a sort on the concatenation of the partition and the order keys. It's like order by x, x.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the text from 70-461 training kit:

> It might seem like the output is sorted by empid, but that’s not
> guaranteed. What could  be more confusing is that if you run the query
> repeatedly, it seems like the result keeps being  returned in the same
> order; but again, that’s not guaranteed. When the database engine (SQL
> Server in this case) processes this query, it knows that it can return
> the data in any order be-  cause there is no explicit instruction to
> return the data in a specif i c order. It could be that, due  to
> optimization and other reasons, the SQL Server database engine chose
> to process the data  in a particular way this time. There’s even some
> likelihood that such choices will be repeated if  the physical
> circumstances remain the same. But there’s a big difference between
> what’s likely  to happen due to optimization and other reasons and
> what’s actually guaranteed.
>
> The database engine may—and sometimes
> does—change choices that can affect the or-  der in which rows are
> returned, knowing that it is free to do so. Examples for such changes
> in  choices include changes in data distribution, availability of
> physical structures such as indexes,  and availability of resources
> like CPUs and memory. Also, with changes in the engine after  an
> upgrade to a newer version of the product, or even after application
> of a service pack,  optimization aspects may change. In turn, such
> changes could affect, among other things, the  order of the rows in
> the result.
>
> In short, this cannot be stressed enough: A query that
> doesn’t have an explicit instruc-  tion to return the rows in a
> particular order doesn’t guarantee the order of rows in the result.
> clause to the query, and that’s the focus of the next section.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.. it "might" retain whatever the current order is in the table.

```
;
WITH    cte
AS (SELECT
      primKey,
      name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY primKey ORDER BY primKey) AS [rn]
    FROM
      TestStage
    )
DELETE
    t
FROM
    TestStage t
    JOIN cte ON t.primKey = cte.primKey
                AND t.name = cte.NAME
WHERE
    cte.rn < (SELECT MAX (rn) FROM cte WHERE primKey = t.primKey)
```

Here's a test for you to see if you can get the order to change. Figure out how many times it takes for the order to break.  Then figure out if it's worth risking.

```
DECLARE @TestStage TABLE(
    primKey int,
    name varchar(50),
    Flag varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TestStage VALUES
(12,'DDD','I'),(15,'EEE','N'),(12,'AAA','I'),(16,'MMM','N')

DECLARE @TestStageOrder TABLE(
    primKey int,
    name varchar(50),
    Flag varchar(10),
    [order] int
)

DECLARE @TestCount INT = 0
WHILE @TestCount < 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TestStageOrder
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY primKey ORDER BY primKey)
    FROM @TestStage
    SET @TestCount = @TestCount + 1
END

SELECT  primKey, name, Flag, [order], COUNT(*) 
FROM    @TestStageOrder
GROUP BY primKey, name, Flag, [order]
```

Comment: This works. But based on the previous responses it doesn't necessarily have to.

Comment: Yes be aware on production. There is no guarantee that it will always delete same rows. This is the simple fact.

Comment: i said he can try it.. you can too for all i care.. he can use `Select` before delete to see if it gets the records he want to delete.  Maybe it gives @that_me123 the result he wants, maybe it don't.  This is one of those cases where the OP decides what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @user1221684, I don't agree. He may see one result when selecting but when deleting it can delete other rows, not those that he saw. The query is obviously incorrect. You can change ordering in your cte as `order by 'blablabla'` and it will be absolutely the same.

Comment: Select into temp table then.. check results.. then delete where name and primkey in temp table.. do i have to think of everything for you Giorgi?

Comment: @user1221684 you don't want to give up :) ok, lets crush one more myth. Insert into temp table. And what? You will have to join temp table on prim key(notice that his prim key is NOT PRIMARY KEY) you will end up with exactly the same , absolutely the same...

Comment: You just don't get the problem man... I have 3 rows  `1 bla 5`, `1 bla 5`, `1 bla 5`. Delete all but last. Can you? Which is last?

Comment: Ok join with primkey and name. You get in temp table some primkey and some name. You look an that name and see dddd. How do you know that dddd was last in excel? You can check it of course but if you have thousand of rows?

Comment: I get the problem.  I'm just offering query suggestions to help him try to sort the data and delete based on the order of the records in table.  Maybe I'm only giving him a 99% success rate.  Better than nothing, which is what you've offering

Comment: Giorgi - I have another question(Please don't lose your patience-My sql knowledge is not as advanced as yours and this forum is meant for learning) - How does TOP work then? So will TOP 100 return different rows each time?Because TOP does not require an explicit ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @that_me123, whithout order by yes it can return different result sets. It is basics. Nothing personal man, just healthy criticism. Without explicit order by clause ordering can be any.

Comment: key word is "can".  that's why i said "might" in my answer.  You can run the same query 9 bazillion times and get the same result.  But not 9 bazillion 1